# Navigation between statically generated pages painfully slow in dev mode next.js

Tags: performance, next.js

Since I added `getStaticPaths` to pages navigation between pages in development mode (`next dev`) became painfully slow. Are there any means to optimize this? I have tried to memoize results of related asynchronous calls to database but it seems like did not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

When navigating to a new page in dev mode, Next needs to compile the page you are going to. So it is common that there is some time in between navigation.

Also from [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development):

> In development, `getStaticProps` is called on every request.

Comment: It takes much longer for me, it feels like `getStaticPaths` is called everytime and then `getStaticProps` for every path.

Comment: `getStaticPaths` also runs on every request in dev mode [according to the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development-1)

Comment: Yeah so I am looking for a ways to optimize this, right now this is way too slow for development mode. The only thing comes to mind is limiting amount returned by getStaticProps manually in development mode, but I was wondering if there is official workaround for this...

Comment: @Aleksey did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @insivika Nope I did not find any clean solution. In my particular case I am using "fallback" behaviour and I made getStaticPaths return empty array in development mode(ie checking process.env.NODE_ENV). This way Next.JS does not pre-render all the pages in development mode.